# To show that the Stiefel Manifold is compact and Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I have been given the following space:

$$X=V_m(\mathbb{R}^n)=\{(v_1,\cdots,v_m)\in \mathbb{R}^n \times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^n \ \vert \ v_1,\cdots,v_m \ \text{are linearly independent}\}$$

And we have defined the following equivalence relation $\sim$
$$(v_1,\cdots,v_m)\sim(v'_1,\cdots,v'_m) \ \text{iff}\ (v_1,\cdots,v_m) \ \text{and} \ (v'_1,\cdots,v'_m) \ \text{span the same}\ m-\text{plane}$$

I have to show that $X/\sim \ $ is compact, Hausdorff and each of it's points has a neighbourhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{m(n-m)}$

Now, X has the induced topology from the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$. But I have no idea on how to proceed. I have also been provided the following hint, but I don't know how to use it.

**Hint:** if $\mathbb{R}^n=V \bigoplus W$ then one can view $V$ as the graph of a linear mapping $V \rightarrow W$, namely, the zero mapping. What other subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $\dim V$ can be regarded as graphs of linear mappings $V \rightarrow W$

Any kind of assistance is helpful! Especially if someone can explain to me how the hint might relate to the question.

Comment: I assume that you do not know the quotient manifold theorem: let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $G$ a Lie group acting smoothly on $M$ and $x\in M$, then if $G\cdot x$ is locally closed, it is a submanifold of $M$ and $G\cdot x=G/G_x$. Here, you can apply this result to $M=(\mathbb{R}^n)^m$, $G=O(n)$ with its diagonal action and $x=(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. In the end, $V_m(\mathbb{R}^n)=O(n)/O(n-m)$.

Comment: I would't say that I'm completely aware of the theorem, but having done a course I can see that it'll be true. But this is from a Basic Graduate Topology course, and I don't think I can invoke Differential Geometry here. Should I mention that in the question? I'm hoping to be led to a solution (via hints from the great folks here) that's derived solely from topological definitions

Comment: Also, to point out. The definition of a Stiefel Manifold given here is that the elements are basis, and not orthonormal basis. So I don't think the action of $O(n)$ is the correct one

Comment: You are right, you are working with what we usually call the Grassmannian of $m$-planes of $\mathbb{R}^n$ denoted by $\operatorname{Gr}(n,m)$. The reasoning is quite similar except that $x$ and the stabilizer will be different. In the end $\operatorname{Gr}(n,k)=O(n)/(O(m)\times O(n-m))$.

Comment: I have this query - Clearly $X$ is not compact, then can $X/\sim$ be compact?

Comment: And since $X$ is the non-compact Steifel Manifold, we have $X = GL(n)/GL(n-m)$

Comment: Sure, they are many examples of non-compact spaces which have compact quotients: if $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $(x,y)\sim (x+1,y),(x,y+1)$, then $X/\sim$ is the $2$-torus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

We have 
$$X=V_m(\mathbb{R}^n)=\{(v_1,\cdots,v_m)\in \mathbb{R}^n \times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^n \ \vert \ v_1,\cdots,v_m \ \text{are linearly independent}\}$$ as a topological subspace with the induced topology from $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$

We introduce the function 
$$\text{gs}: \mathbb{R}^n \times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^n \\ (v_1,\cdots,v_m) \mapsto \text{gs}(v_1,\cdots,v_m)$$ where $\text{gs}(v_1,\cdots,v_m)$ is the Gram-Schmidt Orthonormalisation of $(v_1,\cdots,v_m)$

We now define the subspace $X_* \subset X$:
$$X_*=\{\text{gs}(v_1,\cdots,v_m) \ \vert \ (v_1,\cdots,v_m) \in V_m(\mathbb{R}^n)\}$$
which is our familiar compact Stiefel Manifold.

We have defined the following equivalence relation $\sim$
$$(v_1,\cdots,v_m)\sim(v'_1,\cdots,v'_m) \ \text{iff}\ \ \text{Span}(v_1,\cdots,v_m) = \text{Span}(v'_1,\cdots,v'_m)$$
and we have the map $\pi:X \rightarrow X/\sim$

We clearly see that $\pi(X_*)=X/\sim \implies \pi|_{X_*}:X_* \rightarrow X/\sim$ is a continuous surjective function and hence $X/\sim$ is compact.

We know that the $X/\sim$ is a manifold of dimension $m(n-m)$ hence any open  neighbourhood is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{m(n-m)}$